# Splitting ascii/unicode string

Tags: python, unicode, split, delimiter

I am trying to decode ID3v2 (MP3 header) protocol using python. The format of the data to be decoded is as follows.

`s1`, `s2`, ... `sn-1` are unicode (utf-16/utf-8) strings, and last string 'sn' may be unicode or binary string.

```
data = s1+delimiters+s2+delimiters+...+sn
```

Where, delimiter for utf-16 is `'\x00'+'\x00'`
and delimiter for utf-8 is `'\x00'`

I get `data` along with unicode-type. Now I have to extract all the strings (`s1`, `s2`, ... `sn`) from `data`. For this I am using `split()` as follows,

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def extractStrings(encoding_type, data):
    if(encoding_type == "utf-8"): delimitors = '\x00'
    else: delimitors = '\x00'+'\x00'
    return data.split(delimitors)

def main():        
    # Set-1
    encoding_type = "utf-8"
    delimitors = '\x00'
    s1="Hello".encode(encoding_type)
    s2="world".encode(encoding_type)
    data = s1+delimitors+s2
    print extractStrings(encoding_type, data)

    # Set-2
    encoding_type = "utf-16"
    delimitors = '\x00'+'\x00'
    s1="Hello".encode(encoding_type)
    s2="world".encode(encoding_type)
    data = s1+delimitors+s2
    print extractStrings(encoding_type, data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

output:

```
['Hello', 'world']

['\xff\xfeH\x00e\x00l\x00l\x00o', '\x00\xff\xfew\x00o\x00r\x00l\x00d\x00']
```

It works for set-1 data but doesn't work for set-2.
Since, 'data' in set-2

```
'\xff\xfeH\x00e\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00\x00\x00\xff\xfew\x00o\x00r\x00l\x00d\x00'
                             ^               ^
```

has an extra `'\x00'` precedes delimiter, due to letter '0', its unable to do a proper job.

Can anyone help me to decode 'data' properly for both the cases?

**Update:**

I will try to simply the issue.
s1 = encoded (utf-8/utf-16) string

s2 = binary string (not unicode)

delimiter for utf-16 is `'\x00'+'\x00'`, and delimiter for utf-8 is `'\x00'`

data = (s1+delimiter)+s2

Can anyone help me to extract s1 and s2 from 'data' ?

Update2: Solution

The following code works for my requirement,

```
def splitNullTerminatedEncStrings(self, data, encoding_type, no_of_splits):
data_dec = data.decode(encoding_type, 'ignore')
chunks = data_dec.split('\x00', no_of_splits) 
enc_str_lst = []
for data_dec_seg in chunks[:-1]: 
    enc_str_lst.append(data_dec_seg.encode(encoding_type)) 
data_dec_chunks = '\x00'.join(chunks[:-1])   
if(data_dec_chunks): data_dec_chunks += '\x00'
data_chunks = data_dec_chunks.encode(encoding_type) 
data_chunks_len = len(data_chunks)
enc_str_lst.append(data[data_chunks_len:]) # last segment
return enc_str_lst
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention, last string(sn) may not be a unicode string. While decoding APIC (album-art) frame, sn is binary(image) string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for my requirement,

```
def splitNullTerminatedEncStrings(self, data, encoding_type, no_of_splits):
data_dec = data.decode(encoding_type, 'ignore')
chunks = data_dec.split('\x00', no_of_splits) 
enc_str_lst = []
for data_dec_seg in chunks[:-1]: 
    enc_str_lst.append(data_dec_seg.encode(encoding_type)) 
data_dec_chunks = '\x00'.join(chunks[:-1])   
if(data_dec_chunks): data_dec_chunks += '\x00'
data_chunks = data_dec_chunks.encode(encoding_type) 
data_chunks_len = len(data_chunks)
enc_str_lst.append(data[data_chunks_len:]) # last segment
return enc_str_lst
```

Answer (score 4):

> Where, delimiter for utf-16 is '\x00'+'\x00' and delimiter for utf-8 is '\x00'

Not exactly. The delimiter for UTF-16 is `\0\0` only at a code unit boundary. One `\0` at the end of one code unit followed by `\0` at the start of another code unit does not constitute a delimiter. The ID3 standard, talking about byte 'synchronisation' implies that this isn't the case, but it's wrong.

[Aside: unfortunately many tag-reading tools do take it literally that way, with the result that any sequence with a double-zero-byte in (eg U+0100,U+0061 `Āa` in UTF-16BE, or, as you discovered, any ASCII at the end of a string in UTF-16LE) will break the frame. As a result, UTF-16 text formats (UTF-16+BOM 0x01 and UTF-16BE 0x02) are completely unreliable and should be avoided by all tag writers. And text format 0x00 is unreliable for anything but pure-ASCII. UTF-8 is the winner!]

If you have a list-of-encoded-terminated-strings structure like those specified for the `T` frames (other than `TXXX`), then the simple approach is to just decode them before splitting on the U+0000 terminator:

```
def extractStrings(encoding_type, data):
    chars = data.decode(encoding_type)
    # chars is now a Unicode string, delimiter is always character U+0000
    return chars.split(u'\0')
```

If `data` is a whole ID3 frame I'm afraid you can't process it with a single `split()`. Frames other than the `T` family contain a mixture of encoded-terminated-strings, ASCII-only-terminated-strings, binary objects (which have no termination) and integer byte/word values. `APIC` is one such, but for the general case you'd have to know the structure of every frame you want to parse in advance, and consume each field one-by-one, finding each terminator manually as you go.

To find the code-unit-aligned terminator in UTF-16-encoded data without misinterpreting `Āa` et al, you could use a regex, eg:

```
ix= re.match('((?!\0\0)..)*', data, re.DOTALL).end()
s, remainder= data[:ix], data[ix+2:]
```

This isn't a lot of fun really - ID3v2 is not a very clean format. Of the top of my head and untested, this sort of thing is how I might approach it:

```
p= FrameParser(data)
if frametype=='APIC':
    encoding= p.encoding()
    mimetype= p.string()
    pictype= p.number(1)
    desc= p.encodedstring()
    img= p.binary()

class FrameParser(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data= data
        self._ix= 0
        self._encoding= 0

    def encoding(self): # encoding byte - remember for later call to unicode()
        self._encoding= self.number(1)
        if not 0<=self._encoding<4:
            raise ValueError('Unknown ID3 text encoding %r' % self._encoding)
        return self._encoding

    def number(self, nbytes= 1):
        n= 0
        for i in nbytes:
            n*= 256
            n+= ord(self._data[self._ix])
            self._ix+= 1
        return n

    def binary(self): # the whole of the rest of the data, uninterpreted
        s= self._data[self._ix:]
        self._ix= len(self._data)
        return s

    def string(self): # non-encoded, maybe-terminated string
        return self._string(0)

    def encodedstring(self): # encoded, maybe-terminated string
        return self._string(self._encoding)

    def _string(self, encoding):
        if encoding in (1, 2): # UTF-16 - look for double zero byte on code unit boundary
            ix= re.match('((?!\0\0)..)*', self._data[self._ix:], re.DOTALL).end()
            s= self._data[self._ix:self._ix+ix]
            self._ix+= ix+2
        else: # single-byte encoding - look for first zero byte
            ix= self._data.find('\0', self._ix)
            s= self._data[self._ix:self._ix+ix] if ix!=-1 else self._data[self._ix:]
            self._ix= ix if ix!=-1 else len(self._data)
        return s.decode(['windows-1252', 'utf-16', 'utf-16be', 'utf-8][encoding])
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention, last string(sn) may not be a unicode string. While decoding APIC (album-art) frame, sn is binary(image) string.

Comment: Binary strings like the APIC 'picture data' should not be sent through any of this text processing code - they're neither potentially-Unicode nor zero-terminated.

Comment: I just want to extract(split) 'data' into segments s1, s2 .. sn. Then I will process only text and deal with binary data separately.

Comment: Oh... if you're talking about completely parsing an ID3 frame I'm afraid it's a lot more complicated than that. updated

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you decode the strings first?

Python 2:

```
decoded = unicode(data, 'utf-8')
# or
decoded = unicode(data, 'utf-16')
```

Python 3:

```
decoded = str(data, 'utf-8')
# or
decoded = str(data, 'utf-16')
```

Then you work directly with encoding-agnostic data and the delimiters are always a single null.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention, last string(sn) may not be a unicode string. While decoding APIC (album-art) frame, sn is binary(image) string.